# Nice topic for semi-Markov process

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

I have a presentation to give on Markov Renewal Theory and Semi Markov processes but I cannot really find enough "interesting" examples to talk about, apart from the usual finance-related ones. It seems to be all about equations and integrals and seems quite dull to me.

I am not sure if the book I am referring to, Cinlar, is good for this purpose. Markov chain has many interesting examples and topics to talk about, like card shuffling, random walks, etc. I am not sure if such interesting elements are there in semi markov processes, behind all those limit theorems and equations, it seems.

Comment: "Interesting" is subjective, but Markov-modulated Poisson processes are one area to look into.

Comment: Thanks for the reference but a glance at references tells me it deals with Markov chains, not really semi-Markov processes or Markov Renewal Theory. I am really talking about "nice" applications, like modelling something using SMP, or an application to artificial intelligence or something like that